# Android app preferences page doesn't show toolbar

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to add a preferences page to my Android app.

I've added an `<item>` to my `<menu>` that gets "inflated" in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to make it appear in the `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` in `main_activity.xml`.

[image]

**(1)** it shows up as the cog icon that I added, not as the three dots -- why? How do you get the three dots?

When I go to the settings page my toolbar disappears, but in all the examples the toolbar shows the title and a back button.
I have edited the `manifest.xml` to add the `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` stuff.

**(2)** why does my toolbar disappear?

I've defined a list of values another list of labels to use in a `<ListPreference>` but it doesn't work.

```
    <ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Select units"
        android:entries="@array/units_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/units_values"
        android:key="list"
        android:summary="Click to show a list to choose from"
        android:title="Units" />
```

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="units_values">
        <item>miles</item>
        <item>km</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="units_names">
        <item>miles</item>
        <item>km</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**3** Why isn't this working?! I really can't see what I've got wrong.

[image]

Comment: Why voted down?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the `<item>` in the `<menu>` have their icons shown in the toolbar, but if there isn't enough room then the three dots appear automatically and the overflowed items go in there.

This can be controlled to some extent with the attribute `app:showAsAction` on the `<menu>` items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with items not appearing is that that the text is black.

It can be changed in `styles.xml` with:

```
<item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/text</item>
```

and some *others*, although it appears not to be document what the names of those *other* colours are -- typical.